Area of shaded part of a Semi-circle inscribed in a right triangle
As shown in the diagram, CD = 5 cm, CF = 1 cm. O is the centre of the semi-circle inscribed in a right triangle with angle A = 90 degree. Find the area of the green shaded part.
I may use pythagoras theorem or similarity to solve this problem, but not trigonometry.
I have tried as follows:
1). Draw a line joining O to D and a line joining O to E. These two lines will be perpendicular to the AC and AB respectively.
2). Let FO be x cm.
3). Using pythagoras theorem on right triangle DOC, forming $x^2$ + $5^2$ = $(x+1)^2$. I solve for x which turns out to be 12.
4). Since OE is perpendicular to AB, AC // EO, hence, triangle BEO is similar to triangle BAC. Since DO = EO and angle DOE = angle OEA = angle DAE = 90 degree thus ADOE is a square.
5). Using similarity ratio on triangle BEO and triangle to BAC =>
12 : 17 = EB : (12+ EB), EB is found to be 28.8
6). Area of green shaded portion  = area of triangle ABC – area of semi-circle
$ 0.5 \times 17 \times 40.8 - 0.5 \times \pi \times 12 \times 12 = 121 $
Is my answer and approach correct?


Your answer is correct.
You can get the area of $\triangle ABC$ directly from $|\triangle DOC|=30$ by multiplying by the scaling factor squared, i.e. $\left(\frac{17}{5}\right)^2\cdot30=346.8$.
